# Парсинг сайта с авторизацией на python

Tags: python, парсер

Хочу сделать парсер страницы сайта, но там нужна авторизация и соответственно переход на данную страницу. Пробую реализовать это с помощью Requests и BS. Получилось только авторизоваться, вытянуть HTML код не могу, проверил через .status_code и .url, видно что открылась страница после авторизаци, требуется перейти на другую страницу этого сайта будучи уже авторизованным и оттуда уже тянуть HTML код, как это сделать, подскажите.

```
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

session = requests.Session()
auth = session.post('https://login.kundelik.kz/login', data={'login':'login','password':'pass'})
res = session.get('https://kundelik.kz/feed')
print(res.status_code)
print(res.url)
```

Comment: Мб дело в том, что сайты на разных доменах?
По идее все должно работать, анализируйте, что дает вам сайт.
session.cookies.keys()
Попробуйте посмотреть, что находится в Set-Cookie в теле HTTP ответа

Comment: ['QundelikAuth_a', 'a_r_p_i', 'sst', 't0', 't1', 't2', 'QundelikAuth_l'] - это выдаёт session.cookies.keys()
https://imgur.com/a/5cGlr4t - а вот что находится в set-cookie, вопрос как этим воспользоваться? авторизация проходит по адресу https://login.kundelik.kz/login , после авторизации нас закидывает https://kundelik.kz/feed/ , мне же нужно спарсить https://schools.kundelik.kz/marks.aspx?school=1000005993817&tab=week , как?